# Can I quickly disable and enable intellisence for a particular file in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

Can I quickly disable and enable intellisence (and any other features employing on-the-fly interpretation of the code being edited) for a particular file in Visual Studio 2010? It works to slow on my laptop sometimes, causing the text I type (even comments) in a Visual Studio source editor window to appear with one symbol per 3 seconds speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Build Action on the file in question from "Compile" to "Content" and Intellisense won't kick in.

Once you're done, set it back to "Compile" and you're set.